# What happens when two or more philosophers check the mutex to be 1 and at the same time down the mutex and enter test function

Tags: c, multithreading, dining-philosopher

```
#define N 5 /* number of philosophers */
#define LEFT (i + N−1) % N /* number of i’s left neighbor */
#define RIGHT (i + 1) % N /* number of i’s right neighbor */
#define THINKING 0 /* philosopher is thinking */
#define HUNGRY 1 /* philosopher is trying to get for ks */
#define EATING 2 /* philosopher is eating */

typedef int semaphore; /* semaphores are a special kind of int */

int state[N]; /* array to keep track of everyone’s state */
semaphore mutex = 1; /* mutual exclusion for critical regions */
semaphore s[N]; /* one semaphore per philosopher */

void philosopher(int i) /* i: philosopher number, from 0 to N−1 */
{
    while (TRUE) /* repeat forever */
    {
        think(); /* philosopher is thinking */
        take forks(i); /* acquire two for ks or block */

        eat(); /* yum-yum, spaghetti */
        put forks(i); /* put both for ks back on table */
    }
}

void take forks(int i) /* i: philosopher number, from 0 to N−1 */
{
    down(&mutex); /* enter critical region */
    state[i] = HUNGRY; /* record fact that philosopher i is hungry */
    test(i); /* tr y to acquire 2 for ks */
    up(&mutex); /* exit critical region */
    down(&s[i]); /* block if for ks were not acquired */
}

void put forks(i) /* i: philosopher number, from 0 to N−1 */
{
    down(&mutex); /* enter critical region */
    state[i] = THINKING; /* philosopher has finished eating */
    test(LEFT); /* see if left neighbor can now eat */
    test(RIGHT); /* see if right neighbor can now eat */
    up(&mutex); /* exit critical region */
}

void test(i) /* i: philosopher number, from 0 to N−1 */
{
    if (state[i] == HUNGRY && state[LEFT] != EATING && state[RIGHT] != EATING)
    {
        state[i] = EATING;
        up(&s[i]);
    }
}
```

In this code, as you may see, we have a mutex that is initially one which means that no philosopher is testing whether the forks are free or not. What happens when two or more philosophers check the mutex at the same time and happen to see that the mutex is one and both at the same time down the mutex and enter the function to test the whether forks are free or not? Can this happen or not is my question?

Answer (score 3):

If you were using real mutexes and real semaphores (as found in [POSIX Pthreads](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09), or C11 [§7.26 Threads `<threads.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.26)), then you'd find that a mutex ensures that you cannot have a situation where "two or more philosophers check the mutex at the same time".  That's what 'mutual exclusion' means.

However, you're not using "real mutexes" or "real semaphores"; you are using a plain `int` as a 'semaphore' to implement what you're calling a 'mutex'.  There is no mutual exclusion guaranteed with a plain `int` — and you can't easily achieve it using plain C.  Therefore there is a real risk that you could have multiple philosophers checking the mutex at the same time.  The code is not safe if the program is multithreaded.

We have to say "if the program is multithreaded" because the program is not an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) (or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  It is missing the main program, so it is not possible to tell how the code shown is actually executed.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be worried about the possibility of two philosophers checking the mutex at the same time.  For a mutex to work correctly, this must somehow be made impossible.

If you are using the C library's mutexes and semaphores, the C library guarantees that it *is* impossible.  Specifically, in this code:

```
void take_forks(int i) /* i: philosopher number, from 0 to N−1 */
{
    down(&mutex); /* enter critical region */
```

if two or more threads call `down` simultaneously on an unlocked mutex, `down` will grant the lock to exactly one of those threads, and will return immediately for that thread.  All the other threads will be "blocked" until the thread that holds the lock releases it by calling `up`.  Then one of the waiting threads will receive the lock, `down` will return in that thread, and so on.

Now, you wrote

```
typedef int semaphore; /* semaphores are a special kind of int */
```

and that makes me think that you're *not* using the C library's semaphores, you're assigned to implement them yourself.  You need to know that this *cannot be done* using ordinary C.  In fact, it cannot be done using ordinary machine language.  You have to use special *atomic* machine instructions to make this work.¹  The 2011 revision of the C standard includes special features for accessing those instructions; start by reading the documentation for [stdatomic.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).

Be aware that synchronization primitives are tricky to get right, even for experts.  If there's any way you can write this program using semaphores and/or mutexes that someone else has already implemented for you, then you should do it that way.

---

¹ If you are working with a computer that only has one CPU -- that is, it can't execute more than one thread simultaneously -- and you have the ability to disable interrupts, then the atomic machine instructions are not strictly necessary, but it's better to use the atomic machine instructions anyway, so that the compiled program will still work if it's ever moved to a computer with more than one CPU.

Comment: Re "this cannot be done using ordinary C," I don't know if this would even work anymore on modern computer systems, but mutual exclusion primitives were implemented in software before they ever were supported by hardware: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm

Comment: @SolomonSlow Note the very last paragraph of the "discussion" section: _Lamport's bakery algorithm assumes a sequential consistency memory model. Few, if any, languages or multi-core processors implement such a memory model._ I think judicious use of C11's `atomic_load` and `atomic_store` would make this algorithm sound on modern hardware, but don't ask me exactly which memory accesses need that treatment.